# "Email me new responses to my posts" is missing a top margin

Tags: bug, design, mobile-chrome

"Email me new responses to my posts" is too high:

[image]

As you can see it is too close to the edge of the question box. Can we move it down a little? I am on Chrome (version 103.0.5060.71) for Android, resolution 2220×1080 on mobile.

Note that the "Email me new responses to my posts" checkbox will only be visible if the "Inbox" email setting is `Off` on the [Email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) page.